# How to use the different background colors for the splash screen?

Tags: android

I Implemented the splash Screen in android with image and background colour (black).Now I want to implement the splash screen with the multiple background colours (like black and then blue).The Image should be stable.I am using the transparent image. Anyone know the solution for this?

```
Launcher_Background.xml:

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:opacity="opaque">
<item>
<bitmap
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/splashscreen" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something similar then I have already written the code. through padding, you can adjust the shape size. Hopefully, It will help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/answer_icon" />
</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I want to set the background colour like black with image.After a second same image with different background colour like white.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.WHITE));
```

OR

```
setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Comment: Can you please explain.Where will i use this?

Comment: Use it in splash screen activity onCreate().

Comment: public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
    
    }
     }